# Loading a Large Form in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing a web app using C# MVC.  There is a portion of the app where users can create/edit content that has a structure somewhat like this:

```
Public Class Example
{
    Public string Name { get; set; }
    Public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

Public Class LineItem
{
    Public string Key { get; set; }
    Public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The editor allows them to add/edit/delete/reorder line items which is fine until there are a lot of them.  After there are a bunch, things get super slow.  I need to figure out how to load the form and allow editing of it without bringing things to a crawl.  I'd thought about paging but I'm not sure how I would handle reordering of the items in that case.

I realize this may be a bit too open ended but if not, I hope someone has some good ideas.

Loading of the form is done using an editor template like so:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.LineItems.Count; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LineItems[i], new { Hidden = (i > 10) })
}
```

The editor template is:

```
@model TheRandomizer.Generators.Assignment.LineItem

<div class="form-group row" name="LineItem" data-item-row>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-10", @title = "The name of the item." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Weight, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "1", @title = "The weight for this item when selecting from this item name list." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Next, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @title = "The next item to use after this one is evaluated." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Next, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Variable, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @title = "The name of the variable to store the result in." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Variable, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Expression, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 1, @style = "max-width: 100%", @title = "The expression to evaluate when this item is selected." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Expression, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" name="DeleteItem" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="DeleteItem" title="Delete Parameter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs btn-group-vertical">
            <button name="MoveUp" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="MoveItemUp" title="Move this parameter up"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></button>
            <button name="MoveDown" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="MoveItemDown" title="Move this parameter down"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What part is slow? The loading of the data? The browser? How many records are you dealing with?

Comment: Maybe show us how you load the items and from where you load them. There is not enough info for us to give you advice

Comment: please note that asp.net mvc questions should not be tagged in model-view-controller as it is for general design pattern questions not asp.net mvc framework

Comment: Assuming you do not have any DB issues, perhaps try to keep your view models as lightweight as possible and lazy load data where you can to minimize browser rendering.

Comment: What are you doing to the `LineItems` List? Want to ensure there isn't logic running in a `For` loop, that can be moved outside the loop.

Comment: @mason The slowness is in building the form and in the browser once the form is loaded.  The record that is brought the issue to light has 3,000 line items.  This isn't the usual case to be fair but it is possible.

Comment: There is no need to load 3,000 records. How many do you reasonably expect a user to interact with on the page at a time? 10? 20? 30? You need to page your data. There's plenty of examples out there for how to implement paged data in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @mason, I agree.  My issue with paging is that I'm not sure how to handle reordering of records by the user when they get to the end or beginning of a page.

Comment: You just maintain the same sort order and request the next set of records based on the same page size. Again, look up some examples.

Comment: @mason, thank you for the replies. I am currently using the DataTables plugin for my search paging/sorting and it works fine.  What I can't find is a solution that works with forms and allows me to get back all of the data that was changed in one submit.